# .Net Does default persistence service in Windows workflows use caching capabilities of AppFabric. If yes, can caching be switched off

Tags: .net, workflow, persistence, appfabric-cache

.Net Does default persistence service in Windows workflows use caching capabilities of AppFabric? If yes, can caching be switched off.

Looking what to do in spite AppFabric is discontinued? Is using Persistence only for workflows be safe?

Regards.